# loop to return tags in woocommerce in alphabetical order?

Tags: php, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to make a loop in WordPress from WooCommerce theme to get out all product tags in alphabetical order in a simple way "heading with A below it all tags starts with a letter etc."

I am using the code but its return null.

```
<?php
    $tags = get_tags();
    $html = '<div class="post_tags">';
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

        $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag- 
 >slug}'>";
        $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
     }
    $html .= '</div>';
    echo $html;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns null, because WooCommerce doesn't use tags for products. It uses custom taxonomy called `product_tag`.

So instead of

```
$tags = get_tags();
```

You should use

```
$tags = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
```